# Mirth Connect is hanging while trying to create two dynamic log files

Tags: mirth

I created one channel in mirth environment..in this channel i wrote javascript code for creating two dynamic log files.. whenever i start the channel files were created but the mirth connect is hanged (no more come to normal state, i am restarting every time).. plz help me....

----logs.properties file-----

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG
log4j.logger.DEFAULT_LOGGER=INHERIT, A1
log4j.logger.PROCESS_LOGGER=INHERIT, A2

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=c://test//${cname}//${fname}.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.maxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.A1.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n      %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File=c://test//${cname}//${fname}_ack.log
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.maxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.A2.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n
```

------javascript code--------

```
importPackage(Packages.org.apache.log4j);
var channelName =       Packages.com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.ChannelController.getInstance().getDeployedChannelById(channelId).getName();
var currentDate = DateUtil.getCurrentDate("yyyyMMdd");
Packages.java.lang.System.setProperty("fname", currentDate);
Packages.java.lang.System.setProperty("cname", channelName);

PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:/Program Files/Mirth    Connect/conf/custom/logs.properties");

var logger1 = Logger.getLogger("DEFAULT_LOGGER");
 var logger2 = Logger.getLogger("PROCESS_LOGGER");

logger1.info("default");
logger2.info("process");
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the mirth system logs? 
When you say mirth connect is hanged, do you mean the channel or the whole instance?
Where in your channel is the javascript code being applied?
What else can you tell us about your channel?

Comment: No, it doesn't raise any exception. whole instance was hanged. i wrote the javascript code in transformer. i am just trying to log messages in to separate files...

Answer (score 0):

You might have restrictions applied to the instance of the Mirth Connect to write a file, try to surround your code as follows:

```
var controller = Packages.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
    Packages.java.security.PrivilegedAction(
         /* Your code goes here */
    )
);
```

Alternatively, you can create two separate Log channels with File Writer destinations and route what you need to log there.